# Delphi cross platform: how to check if socket is connected or not

Tags: android, delphi, cross-platform, firemonkey

I know this question is asked a lot, I've done some search before i post my question here but still can not manage to find a solution for my problem.

In Delphi VCL, i can identify whether a socket is connected or not using;

```pascal
if Socket.Connected = True then
```

But in Delphi FMX on Android, there is no such function!

My code:

```pascal
Procedure TForm24.SocketConnect;
var
  FClientSocket: TSocket; 
  Buf: TBytes;
begin
  //Connect to VCL server
  FClientSocket := TSocket.Create(TSocketType.TCP);
  FClientSocket.Connect(string.Empty, '192.168.1.155'+#0, string.Empty, 4851);
  //if FClientSocket.Connected then
  while True do
  begin
    // Receive the message from the VCL server
    SetLength(Buf, 4);        
    FClientSocket.Receive(Buf, 4);
    // Some code here...
  end;
end;
```